# Determine whether two indices are in same row of 2D matrix using arithmetic

Tags: math, matrix, modulo

Is it possible to determine whether two values are in the same row of a 2D matrix using their matrix indices and the length of each row (row lengths are constant) in the matrix using only arithmetic?

```
matrix = [
  [4, 7, 9, 1],
  [5, 1, 3, 3],
  [8, 2, 4, 7],
  [3, 6, 8, 2]
]

start = 4 # matrix index; points to matrix[1][0]
end = 9 # matrix index; points to matrix[2][1]
row_length = 4

# ... are start and end in the same row?
```

I must be overlooking an obvious solution, but wasn't able to come up with one on my own or find a satisfactory one elsewhere.

Comment: `matrix[i][j]` if `i` is same for any two elements `then same row` if `j` is same for any two elements `then same column`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the row number for a given zero-based index by dividing it by the row length--the resulting integer part is the zero-based row number. Here is Python code to check for the same row:

```
if start // row_length == end // row_length:
    # same row
else:
    # different row
```

That `//` is integer division. In a language without that operator:

```
if int(start / row_length) == int(end / row_length):
    # same row
else:
    # different row
```

In your particular example, `4 // 4` is `1` and `9 // 4` is `2`, so those locations are in different rows.

Comment: So, I was overlooking something _very_ obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @pdoherty926: That happens to us all, especially me.